# ¿Como mandar dos datos con lists de Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, laravel-blade

Quiero enviar 2 valores a la vista con `lists` de laravel

```
admin.horarios.create
```

La duda es la siguiente, tengo este código:

```
public function create()
    {

        $docente   = Docente::orderBy('nombre','ASC')
                    ->where('estado',1)
                    ->lists('nombre', 'apellido' 'id');

        return    view('admin.horarios.create')
                ->with('docente', $docente);

    }
```

Pero tengo un error, ya que solo me muestra el nombre y no el apellido.

```
{!! Form::select('id_docente', $docente , null, ['class' => 'form-control input-xs select2']) !!}
```

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 5):

El método lists es obsoleto en estos momentos, deberías utilizar `pluck()` en su lugar.

Par solucionar tu problema puedes usar un **accesor** para generar la cadena que quieres, agrega a tu modelo Docente:

```
public function getFullnameAttribute()
{
    return [$this->nombre . ' ' . $this->apellido];
}
```

Y la consulta sería algo así:

```
$docente = Docente::orderBy('nombre', 'ASC')
                ->where('estado', 1)
                ->pluck('fullname', 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa, es utilizando query builder, y hacer lo siguiente:

```
public function create()
{

    $docente   = Docente::orderBy('nombre','ASC')
                ->selectRaw( " CONCAT('nombre', ' ', 'apellido') as nombre, id " )
                ->where('estado',1)
                ->lists('nombre', 'id');

    return    view('admin.horarios.create')
            ->with('docente', $docente);

}
```

y listo, con eso se debería mostrar nombre y apellido.

Saludos